# blockcypher shows much higher amount transacted

Tags: blockcypher

I sent bitcoin from my localbitcoins.com account to my coinbase.com account. It showed up as 0.00147276 BTC in coinbase but the transaction shows as 0.953 BTC on blockcypher:
[image]
Is there a way for me to actually receive that amount?
Thanks

Comment: This is a very vague question, you’re going to need to provide more details on the tx. If you are not the rightful owner of the 0.95.. btc, why do you think you should receive it?

Comment: I sent bitcoin from my localbitcoins.com account to my coinbase.com account. It showed up as 0.00147276 BTC in coinbase but the transaction shows as 0.953 BTC on blockcypher.

Comment: It sounds like you withdrew 0.0014.. btc, not 0.953 btc. The reason you’re seeing the larger amount reported is that the tx localbitcoins sent to coinbase likely paid out to multiple users, your payout bundled with some others, for efficiency. If your coinbase account was credited with the proper amount (0.0014..btc), then no, there is no way to claim the larger amount transacted.

Comment: Oh. All of my other transactions displayed correctly on blockcypher. I didn't know it could clump together my transaction with other people's so I was super excited that some kind of mistake was made and I'd be receiving more bitcoin than what I sent. :/

Comment: There are other possibilities too (such as localbtc spending a large utxo to pay you out, with the majority being sent to a change address), but without more details I wouldn’t be able to tell you for sure. Don’t feel bad, btc works in ways that are a little different than people are used to, and you’ll never learn if you don’t ask :)

Comment: I sent a lot of bitcoin to the silk road just a few hours before it got shut down years ago, I obviously didn't get any of my bitcoin back. So when I transferred my whole balance from localbitcoins to coinbase I was hoping that some of those lost bitcoins made their way back to me.

Answer (score 2):

I am making the presumption that localbitcoins.com does as many web wallet providers do, amalgamate transactions.

Most likely your transaction was combined by the wallet provider with some others before being broadcast. No, you cannot claim the additional value of the transfer.

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

> Is there a way for me to actually receive that amount?

**No.**

## Explanation

When a TX is broadcasted to the network it uses one or more unspent transactions from your address to make up the total amount you wish to transfer.

*When you use public services wallets (i.e. coinbase, blockchain.info etc,) it could happen that your transaction is broadcasted to the network together with other transactions*, so that's why an explorer as blockcypher shows an amount which is different from the effective amount you sent to your desired address.

*This because BTC transactions need to have at least one input and two outputs.* The input is the unspent coins in the sending address available to spend for the sender. The outputs are , usually, splitted one to the final receiving address and one back to a "change address", created by default from the BTC protocol to increase anonimity and privacy each time you spend bitcoins.

In your screenshot you can see the amount under "Amount Transacted" is much higher than your effective transaction because this value represent the total of the bitcoins which has been "moved" during this transaction. More precisely your tx is 0.00147276 BTC, but to send out your 0.00147276 BTC this transaction used a previous unspent input of 0.953 BTC.

Learn more: [Bitcoin Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction) 
[Coincompare Tx Explanation](https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/guides/bitcoin-transaction-inputs-and-outputs/)